# Fire same bootstrap tooltip for all disabled inputs / ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

What's the best way to intialize Tooltip in a react component and have it fire on all disabled inputs, like a global single call.

i.e. "This cannot be edited" any time you hover over ANY disabled input.

My goal is to NOT have to wrap each of hundreds of inputs individually like this:

```
<Tooltip>
    <input/>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an `Input` component, pass in a bool prop, something like `showValidationMessageAsTooltip`, and, inside `Input` comp., if `showValidationMessageAsTooltip` is true, wrap the `Input` comp. with `Tooltip`.

Code example:

```
return (
     showValidationMessageAsTooltip ? <Tooltip><input {...props}/></Tooltip> : <input {...props} />
);
```

This way, you'll only have to pass in an extra bool prop.

P.S.: There are other, even more efficient ways, especially if you have a form config where each form field has a component defined for it and each form field can have multiple HOC (higher-order comps.) defined in the form config (an array of objects, basically) as well.

But, for now, until you dive deeper into things like `redux-form`, etc., I suggest to stick to the simpler solution.